# How to get these lower legs off?

Tags: maintenance, fork, suspension

Hi I have a fork from a carrera crossfire 2000, the sticker says mg suntour cr 920. I want to full service and overhaul this fork because the suspension is totally stuck and not working!

There are no rebound nuts on the bottom, I am unfamiliar with this design and I don't know how to get these lower legs off! There were screws in the sides of the lower legs but still stuck after removing them.

Here are some pictures, someone suggested to me that these are not meant to be removed?  Is that correct?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: so there are no allen keys or nuts on the bottom of the legs at all?

Comment: Hi, I've taken some more photos uploaded to imgur here https://imgur.com/a/8UOcPIm There are only these little screws in the side of the legs, are they rebound screws? Are these legs not meant to come off? I've managed to get the spring out now, and after trying to clean around the seals I can move the suspension a little back and forth if I push or pull on it really hard. Are these meant to be fully removable? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Most of this type of entry level fork requires a long 5mm allen wrench to disassemble. Remove both the plastic caps from the uppers, shining a flashlight in the whole may make the bolt head visible. An alternative to a long allen wrench is a 3/8 drive 5mm allen socket and a long extension. There are usually no service parts available and the best you can do is clean things up add some grease.

Comment: Thank you I will try this now, I never would have guessed to look inside down into the lower legs. I couldn't get the left top cap off because I don't have a good tool for it. Inside these kind of forks, what will I find inside the left top cap? Is this called a coil suspension? When I try to Google sr suntour cr 920 I don't get any informative results at all, some weird sites selling them but can't find any like service specifications!

Comment: I've had one that required 10mm hex. (so a standard 10mm nut was required). But i second that there won't be much to do in there, other than admiring the mess, probably of rusted-through metal coils, rusty water, and some very dirty grease.